# How to check if list view items are checked or not on button click

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am using a custom List adapter for my list view

layout

```
public class VoterListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Voter> implements Filterable {

private static final String TAG = "VoterListAdapter";
private Context mContext;
private int mResource;
private int lastPosition = -1;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView vid;
    TextView name;
    TextView mNum;
    TextView wNum;
    TextView lmNum;
    TextView rNum;
    CheckBox vote;

}
public VoterListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Voter> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    String vid = getItem(position).getVid();
    String name = getItem(position).getName();
    String mNum = getItem(position).getmNum();
    String wNum = getItem(position).getwNum();
    String lmNum = getItem(position).getLmNum();
    String rNum = getItem(position).getrNum();

    Voter voter = new Voter(vid,name,mNum,wNum,lmNum,rNum);

    final View result;

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
        holder.mNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mNum_text_view);
        holder.wNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wNum_text_view);
        holder.lmNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lmNum_text_view);
        holder.rNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rNum_text_view);
        holder.vote = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vote_check_box);


        result = convertView;

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result = convertView;
    }

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
            (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.loading_down_anim : R.anim.loading_up_anim);
    result.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;

    holder.name.setText(voter.getName());
    holder.mNum.setText(voter.getmNum());
    holder.wNum.setText(voter.getwNum());
    holder.lmNum.setText(voter.getLmNum());
    holder.rNum.setText(voter.getrNum());
    
    return convertView;
}
```

}

My Voter class looks like this

```
public class Voter {

private String vid;
private String name;
private String mNum;
private String wNum;
private String lmNum;
private String rNum;
private CheckBox vote;

public Voter(String vid, String name, String mNum, String wNum, String lmNum, String rNum ) {
    this.vid = vid;
    this.name = name;
    this.mNum = mNum;
    this.wNum = wNum;
    this.lmNum = lmNum;
    this.rNum = rNum;
}

public CheckBox getVote() {
    return vote;
}

public void setVote(CheckBox vote) {
    this.vote = vote;
}

public String getVid() {
    return vid;
}

public void setVid(String vid) {
    this.vid = vid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getmNum() {
    return mNum;
}

public void setmNum(String mNum) {
    this.mNum = mNum;
}

public String getwNum() {
    return wNum;
}

public void setwNum(String wNum) {
    this.wNum = wNum;
}

public String getLmNum() {
    return lmNum;
}

public void setLmNum(String lmNum) {
    this.lmNum = lmNum;
}

public String getrNum() {
    return rNum;
}

public void setrNum(String rNum) {
    this.rNum = rNum;
}
```

}

This is how i set my adapter(may not be relevant)

```
adapter = new VoterListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.adapter_view_layout, voterlist);
    datalistview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have a separate button which should check all items in the custom list view and if they are checked, give me the Voter object.I tried using onItemClickListener() but I am only able to get it work on individual object. I want it to check all items at once when the button is clicked

Comment: Your Voter class is missing a setChecked() and getChecked() member.

Comment: If there are 100 voters and only seven can be displayed then do they keep the checked state al scroll and scroll back?

Comment: So your Voter class misses a boolean indicating the checked state.

Comment: yeah, i tried add many voters in my list, and the checkbox does get checked and unchecked when i scroll. I understand that its happening because the listview item is getting destroyed and recreated. how do i correct it??

Comment: so initially while adding the voters to the list, do i initialize the checked state as false ?

Comment: Indeed. But for testing make some already checked so you see that it works. And implemnent an onCheckedStateChanged listener for the checkbox. There you calll setChecked().

Comment: `and the checkbox does get checked and unchecked when i scroll.` You mean:  and a checked checkbox does get unchecked when i scroll.

Comment: Set the state in getView() like you do with other variables. Your first concern should be to keep the checked state while scrolling.